# re-organize a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a big data file which looks like:

```
ID Time Value
1 BEG 1.2
1 END 2.2
2 BEG 1.7
2 END 0.5
2 SUP 2.4
3 BEG 3.2
```

I want to re-organize this data so it looks like:

```
ID BEG END SUP
1  1.2 2.2 NA
2  1.7 0.5 2.4
3  3.2  NA  NA
```

In other words, I need the values of time, value and sub to be on the same row for each ID.

Comment: `library(tidyr) dt2 <- spread(dt, Time, Value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `dcast` question:

```
require(data.table)
# Your data frame will be called `df`
dt <- data.table(df)
dt.wide <- dcast(dt, ID ~ Time, value.var = "Value")
```